# How to trigger an sql routine on query column values and merge result into powerquery

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery, m

I am working with office 2016 excel and connecting to an Oracle db

I am creating a file for fetching orders, the part number, their desired delivery dates, the actual delivery dates, the average lead time, the average consumption and finally the current stock level.

I have created an sql to fetch the orders and the dates and the lead time. However, in the database, the current stock level is gotten through a procedure that takes input the part number and the location (can be '%' for overall stock level). Now, I can build a query that takes all orders, all part numbers and run the procedure for every single part number, and then build my powerquery but that seems like a hideous waste of processing power.

Question is: Is there a way to append or merge into the powerquery by calling the procedure after I have filtered the initial source results? Thus only running the procedure for orders made the last month or only on filtered part numbers?

I have tried looking the usual places, support.office, google and here but my problem is I (overwhelmingly) get only results from how to append or merge queries (which is trivial and basically a version of the unwanted situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stian,

1. If your procedure is not a stored procedure, but a function, then you can create separate query for this function, and then add new column to a filtered table. This column is getting its value by executing this function with a parameter from another column(s).
2. The other way doing this is creating a view having all the columns you'd like, including that one generated by procedure. Then you query this view in PowerQuery, and apply your filters to the result. This should trigger ***query folding***, which passes your filters to the server, so it optimizes query and doesn't fetch unneeded rows. 
   As far as I know, Native Queries (when you directly white an SQL query to execute) are not subject to query folding. Also, they are quite unsecure and generally an ad-hoc solution. Keep this in mind.

Google for "Query folding in Power Query" if you'd like more info.

Still, for the most optimal scenario I would consider using function instead of procedure (if that's possible, of course), and combining if with a view to get the data you want.

Comment: You are correct, query folding does not occur if you use Native Queries.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I have not succeeded quite yet, but you have lead me towards where a general solution to my specific problem is (may be). Which is the best kind of answer, I still get to figure out the details on my own =). .